# Как редактировать определенные ячейки таблицы Excel через Python?

Tags: python, excel, xls

Начал делать базу данных в Excel файлах, научился записывать и читать файлы, но не могу найти метода или другой библиотеки для редактирования созданного листа Excel

Работал для заполнения файла с библиотекой xlwt
Для чтения использовал xlrd

Пробовал работать через openpyxl, но он не поддерживает расширение .xls(только .xlsx)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: `Начал делать базу данных в Excel файлах` бросьте вы это неблагодарное занятие

Comment: Если уж Вам так нужно делать БД в каких-то файлах и без Microsoft Вы себе жизни не представляете, используйте MS Access

Comment: xlsx формат более простой для работы. Поэтому для него будет больше решений и библиотек чем для xls (который по сути является закрытым форматом). Поэтому правильнее не заморачиваться и использовать xlsx

Comment: newman, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Правильным решением было перейти с .xls на .xlsx, используя библиотеку openpyxl.
У данной библиотеки очень большой функционал:

```
#создаем сам файл\
ws = openpyxl.Workbook()\
(если файл нужно редактировать, то нужно изменить .Workbook() на .load_workbook("Имя файла.xlsx"))

#Создание дефолтного листа\
wb= ws.active

#Переименовать дефолтный лист\
ws.active.title = "Имя листа"

#Заполнение ячейки A1\
wb['A1']="текст, который будет в ячейке"

#Чтобы вывести значение\
print(wb['A1'].value) #value-значение ячейки

#В конце обязательно сохраняем файл\
ws.save("test.xlsx")
```

Я кратко описал, как работает эта библиотека. В ней есть возможность, и создавать новые листы, и красить ячейки, и создавать края.

Подробнее читайте тут: https://docs-python.ru/packages/modul-openpyxl/

Comment: Перед работой не забудьте скачать библиотеку: pip install openpyxl (консоль от имени админа)